# why the formula of coca cola can not be find using chemistry?

Tags: spectroscopy, molecules, structural-formula

i mean we have SPECTROSCOPY to stablish what molecules make a compound

and also we have advanced chemistry

so why is SO HARD to find the formula of coca cola ? simply buy a bottle examine it to check what molecules or ingredients have and copy it :D

but why is so hard ?

Comment: A rough analogy would be that, unless you are an expert baker, knowing a fancy cake contains flour, sugar, and salt won't get you very far.  I think this is a great question at its core, but probably needs to be narrowed down a bit.

Comment: Related question: [Why is the recipe of Coca Cola still a secret?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15007/why-is-the-recipe-of-coca-cola-still-a-secret)

Comment: I think this might be a full-on duplicate @NicolauSakerNeto, but I'll see what other people think.  I did not remember we had that question.